# I want to give Elements padding with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, padding

I gave my elements a class. I then run in javascript

```
document.getElementsByClassName("class").style.padding = "20px"
```

but it didin't work. Is the problem that in javascript padding doesn't work with classes?

Comment: must loop: https://jsfiddle.net/m94jtq94/

Answer (score 2):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like object, so you either need to iterate over all of them in a loop, or specify the individual elements you want to change. It works when you change to an ID because ID's must be unique.

Ex:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('class');
Array.prototype.filter.call(elems, function(testElement){
    testElement.style.padding = "80px" 
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jr53xdcj/)**